# Prepending to ArraySeq without copying it

Tags: scala, seq

In the documentation of `+:` method in `ArraySeq` said that

> A copy of the sequence with an element prepended.

Is there a way to prepend an element without copying the whole `ArraySeq`?

Comment: I dont think so. You could use ArrayBuffer etc for in place append/prepend etc.

Comment: @Samar But it's mutable and we actualy can;t mutate it... What a strange...

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about `Seq` or `ArraySeq`? You mention both. Are you talking about prepending or appending? You mention prepending, but you also mention `:+` which appends.

Comment: No, a `Seq` is not mutable. `Seq` doesn't say anything about mutability, therefore it cannot assume the ability to mutate, therefore it must return copies.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm talking about prepending to `ArraySeq`. Fixed now.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But `ArraySeq` does. It is i package `scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq`.

Comment: Why do you need to append it to the instance? Is it a shared reference?

Comment: `ArraySeq` is a mutable collection of *fixed size*. How are you going to prepend to something that has a fixed size?

Comment: If you are okay, Please accept one of the answer as owner, so that it will be pointer to other users –

Answer (score 1):

Even though ArraySeq is a mutable collection, certain member methods of this collection will return a copy of the collection and not do "in place" transformation. From the [scala doc collections overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html)

> A collection in package scala.collection.mutable is known to have some
>   operations that change the collection in place. So dealing with
>   mutable collection means you need to understand which code changes
>   which collection when.

So, its possible that mutable collections will have some methods that will return copies of the original collection.

On the other hand, its guaranteed that all operations on collections in the scala.collection.immutable package will return copies of the original collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Quoting from the [*Collections Overview*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#array_sequences) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> Array sequences are mutable sequences of **fixed size** which store their elements internally in an `Array[Object]`. They are implemented in Scala by class `ArraySeq`.

Prepending changes the size, ergo it is not possible to prepend to an `ArraySeq`.

They are very similar to `Array`s, which are of course also mutable and have a fixed size.

If you want to change the size, you need a `*Builder` or a `*Buffer`, in this case, an [`ArrayBuffer`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer), which *does* have a [`+=:`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer@+=:(elem:A):ArrayBuffer.this.type) method for prepending.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `ArraySeq` works.
AFAIK there is ***no*** other built in option available.

Means, to adjust the size it has to return new copy :(

```
  scala> val a = List(1)
    a: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> val b = a :+ 2
b: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> println(a)
List(1)
```

**Doc says:**

> abstract def
>   +:(elem: A): ArraySeq[A] [use case] A copy of the array sequence with an element prepended. elem the prepended element returns a new
>   collection of type That consisting of elem followed by all elements of
>   this array sequence. Definition Classes GenSeqLike

Similar function is there in [ArrayBuffer](http://xuwei-k.github.io/scala-library-sxr/scala-library-2.9.1/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.scala.html) as well. 
It also copies to create new one. Below are the snippets for better understanding...

**snippet 1:**

```
/** Prepends a single element to this buffer and returns
   *  the identity of the buffer. It takes time linear in 
   *  the buffer size.
   *
   *  @param elem  the element to append.
   *  @return      the updated buffer. 
   */
  def +=:(elem: A): this.type = {
    ensureSize(size0 + 1)
    copy(0, 1, size0)
    array(0) = elem.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
    size0 += 1
    this
  }
```

**Snippet2:**

```
/** Inserts new elements at the index `n`. Opposed to method
   *  `update`, this method will not replace an element with a
   *  one. Instead, it will insert a new element at index `n`.
   *  
   *  @param n     the index where a new element will be inserted.
   *  @param seq   the traversable object providing all elements to insert.
   *  @throws Predef.IndexOutOfBoundsException if `n` is out of bounds.
   */
  def insertAll(n: Int, seq: Traversable[A]) {
    if (n < 0 || n > size0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString)
    val xs = seq.toList
    val len = xs.length
    ensureSize(size0 + len)
    copy(n, n + len, size0 - n)
    xs.copyToArray(array.asInstanceOf[scala.Array[Any]], n)
    size0 += len
  }
```